# Trouble setting up Twitter Authentication with Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter

I am developing a hybrid mobile app with Angular and I've started to incorporate social login with Firebase. The login screen has two social login options; Facebook and Twitter. The Facebook login seems to be working fine, but Twitter is giving me some issues. Once you click the Facebook login button, a ng-click triggers this code:

```
$scope.facebookLogin = function() {
    $cordovaOauth.facebook("1396105657278668", ["email"]).then(function(result) {
        auth.$authWithOAuthToken("facebook", result.access_token).then(function(authData) {
            $state.go('tabs')
            console.log(JSON.stringify(authData));
        }, function(error) {
            console.error("ERROR: " + error);
        });
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error);
    });
}
```

^ This is working fine

I then tried to do the same thing with Twitter by using $cordovaOAuth.twitter:

```
$scope.twitterLogin = function() {
    $cordovaOauth.twitter("YUS7ONldKLBuYjKxiafx5dajA", ["email"]).then(function(result) {
        auth.$authWithOAuthToken("twitter", result.access_token).then(function(authData) {
            $state.go('tabs')
            console.log(JSON.stringify(authData));
        }, function(error) {
            console.error("ERROR: " + error);
        });
    }, function(error) {
        console.log("ERROR: " + error);
    });
}
```

The problem is that when I click the Twitter button, nothing happens and the logs output a ERROR: null.

Does anybody have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Are you receiving results from (result) from $cordovaOauth.twitter?

Comment: No, I am not receiving anything

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so If i'm not mistaken, the twitter login will require two parameters, one would be your **client id**, and the other would be the **consumer secret**.  Please try this and let me know if you still have problems.

```
$scope.twitterLogin = function() {
        $cordovaOauth.twitter("YUS7ONldKLBuYjKxiafx5dajA", "CONSUMER_SECRET").then(function(result) {
            // 
        }, function(error) {
            //
           console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

Comment: That's actually what I had before I reverted back to trying ["email"]. I am still receiving an ERROR: null

Comment: Oh man, that's strange.   There has to be a problem with the module then.  Check here [link](https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/issues/45) -  There may be a temporary solution you could use

Comment: Also make sure you have the latest version of the module!